# Determining USB device port

Tags: usb, lsusb

```
lsusb | grep UART
```

returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

How can I confirm that the device is at: `/dev/ttyUSB0` **without unplugging** the USB device?

```
ls /dev/tty* | grep USB
```

returns `/dev/ttyUSB0` only when the device is plugged in, which seems to confirm the USB port location.   I am seeking a confirmation process does not involve unplugging the USB device.

## Update:

the USB device is not a disk: it is a [ESP32 microcontroller](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx3KIIBRYWE1NFK/ref=ask_ql_ql_al_hza)

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, type this command: `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk`
You should have enough information to identify your device.

Answer (score 1):

Or try 
`hwinfo --short`
Easy to type and remember and you should have enough information to identify your device.